# Check if Username exists in Android Code

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to check if the Text from my **EditText** is already in the Database. I am really new in **PHP** & **MySQL**.

I tried to receive all the Usernames and check if it equals to the **EditText** Text. At first it looked good. I checked it with

```
if(!UsernameDB.equals(editUsername.getText().toString()){
    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Problem is, that it Toasts it for every Name. So i can't ask if everything is filled in right (**Email**, **Password** etc.) because it says its not matching after it passed the Name that is matching.

Does someone know how i can resolve my Problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the string UsernameDB is what you're expecting? It might help to log out UsernameDB to adb to see the actual value before you do the comparison.

Comment: it is unclear what is UsernameDB is, Post some info about it

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you need to do it by Ajax or is it ok to refresh the site.
Here is an example for refreshing:
First of all you need a Formular (html):

```
<?php include("loginFunktion.php"); ?>
<form action="" method="Post">      
        <input name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="test" value="test">              
</form>
```

Thats the basic of your DB Class (new sheet):

```
<?php 
class DB {
protected $mysqli;

function __construct(){
    $this->host = "***";
    $this->username = "***";
    $this->database = "***";
    $this->password = "***";

}

function connect(){
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s<br/>", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }   
}

function disconnect() {
    // Verbindung beenden
    $this->mysqli->close();
}
}    
?>
```

Now you have in include the class and connect to your DB by the constructor of your class (the following code is the loginFunktion.php sheet):

```
<?php 
    include("dbclassname.php");
    $_DB = new DBData();
    $_DB -> connect();
?>
```

Now you have a connection to your DB and u can do querys:

```
if(isset($_POST["test"])){
$queryCALL ="SELECT user FROM t_user WHERE user_name=".$_REQUEST["name"];
$result = $this->mysqli->query($queryCALL);
$ergebnis=$result->fetch_array()[0];
if(count($ergebnis)>0)
    echo "this name is used";
}
```

If you are new on php ajax is a little bit to complicate for you. Nethertheless thats a good guide:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Next time please add more informations.